# jQuery append() data to a div by doing a .get() from a hyperlink

Tags: ajax, jquery, get

I want to achieve [something like this](http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/books?query=php&vertical=books&dd=0&autosuggest%5Bas%5D=off&autosuggest%5Bas-submittype%5D=default-search&autosuggest%5Bas-grouprank%5D=0&autosuggest%5Bas-overallrank%5D=0&Search=%C2%A0&_r=_iN6OjEUPgVEgEvZj%2b%2bZmQ--&_l=MHzwajeMCXBPHY1KaGPeZQ--&ref=1a3d4e72-48d4-416e-b64f-c15ac08994ea&selmitem=). Here the page automatically loads new content when I scroll down. I want to fetch the new set of data by clicking on a hyperlink at the bottom of my page.

Being a newbie to AJAX, I was checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999872/432720) which is similar to mine, but it isn't working. All I get is an empty Object when I run the code.
Here's the code in my files:

**index.php**

```
<a href="about.php">About Me</a> <br>
<a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a>
<div class="wrap"></div>

<script>
    (function(){
        var wrap = $('div.wrap');
        $('a').on('click', function(e){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.get(href, function(data){
                console.log($(data).find('div.container'));
                $(data).find("div.container").appendTo(wrap);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

**about.php**

```
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>I suck at AJAX ! :-(</p>
</div>
```

**contact.php**

```
<div class="container"><h1>Contact!</h1>
  <form action="#">
  <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
  <p><button type="submit">Save</button></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of empty Object]

Am I missing something? Does `.get()` work inside the callback function of `click()` event? But it works fine when I `.load()` it... Sorry for the big post but I'm totally at a loss here! :/ Please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
    var wrap = $('div.wrap');
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(href, function(data){
            console.log($(data).filter('div.container'));
            wrap.append($(data).filter(".container"));
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})();
```

Comment: It doesn't work! :( It logs the `data` to the console (returns the whole html tags for each pages) but the `.find()` doesn't seem to work on `$(data)`

Comment: I have updated to `.filter()` and added missing line. Does that help?

Comment: `.get` is a simplified `.ajax` and should work here; moreover, `.ajax` only accepts a single object, no `$.ajax(href, {})` syntax.

Comment: @Scott It works! :D Thanks a ton! I love stackoverflow! 

But still I don't quite understand why `.find()` isn't working here?!

Comment: @Scott Nevermind now I got it! ^_^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236431/jquery-append-data-to-a-div-by-doing-a-get-from-a-hyperlink/12236564#comment16399979_12236564

Answer (score 1):

As for why `$.get()` isn't working, you need to get the returned data ready for use by the DOM traversal techniques:

```
(function(){
    var wrap = $('div.wrap');
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(href, function(data){
            var $content = $('<div />').html(data);
            console.log( $content.find('div.container') );
            $content.find("div.container").appendTo(wrap);
        });
    });
})();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax6xS/) Note that jsFiddle's testing resources required `$.post` instead of `$.get`, but the principle is the same.

---

Similar thing, accomplished using `.load()` ([**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VQ5SY/)):

```
(function(){
    var wrap = $('div.wrap');
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<div />')
            .load(href +' div.container')
            .appendTo(wrap)
            .children(':first-child')
            .unwrap();
    });
})();​
```

Comment: Yeah. That works, but I'm trying to _append_ the value to the `.wrap` div **index.php** each time I click on the link. I showed an example in the link.

Comment: @maxxon15 Fair enough. You could always load it into a hidden `<div>` then append the contents to `.wrap` from that as an alternative. Anyway, have a look at the updated code/demo and let me know if that solves your prob.

Comment: It does work! Thanks! :) But I kinda lost it at
`var $content = $('<div />').html(data);`

I don't understand ....
First: Why the `html()` ? Isn't `data` in HTML format already?
Second: Are you wrapping it with a new `<div>`? This is not the `.container` div right?

Comment: `.find()` searches for *descendants* of the current element, so if the current element is already what you're searching for, you won't find it. Wrapping it the new `<div>` allows you to abstract out from the content returned from the server, and then traverse freely. (Yes the data is already html, this is just a blank wrapper.)

Comment: **Ooohh**... Now I get it... That's why Scott used `.filter()`! Thanks again! :D