# Can I put two page .load(url)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if I can put two page in load Example :

```
$(function() {
    $(".dislike<?php echo $rapport['id']; ?>").click(function(evt) {
        $("#lik<?php echo $rapport['id']; ?>").load("dislike.php?is=<?php echo $rapport['id']; ?>")
        $("#lik<?php echo $rapport['id']; ?>").load("showdislike.php?is=<?php echo $rapport['id']; ?>")
    });
});
```

It's a like / dislike system

Thanks !

Comment: I wouldn't use `load()` for the first AJAX call but [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

`$.load` will erase the current content of the element. You should have a look to this question

[Can jQuery .load append instead of replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999807/can-jquery-load-append-instead-of-replace)

and use `$.get`as they suggest

EDIT:

> I would like to post with the first link and after reload the div on my page without refresh my principal page.

```
$.post(first_link).done(function() {
    my_div.load(second_link)
});
```

Instead of `.done`, you can use `.success` or `.fail`if you need to handle some special case: see http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Can you make an example I don't uderstand your link ... 

I explain my problem in details. I would like to post with the first link and after reload the div on my page without refresh my principal page.